# JSON (client-side) <-> Java (server-side) <-> JSON (NoSQL DB)

Tags: java, json, nosql, data-conversion

I am currently looking at using a Document-oriented NoSQL database for my application.

The primary motivations for me to think of this move are :

1. My Server-side emits JSON to its clients.
2. My server-side is Java based.
3. Going for a relational database means I need to convert from relational data in DB -> object data in Java code -> JSON document for client consumption (and vice-versa).
4. The ORM overheads involved in Step 3, seem significant enough to be avoided.
5. My database schema could undergo changes and I want to accommodate them easily.
6. Caching (say using Redis or the NoSQL DB itself) maps well with an underlying NoSQL database.
7. Scaling and distribution feel natural with a NoSQL database.

So, given that background in the decision making, I end up with the following data conversions: 
**JSON (to/from client side) <-> Java (on Server-side) <-> JSON Documents in NoSQL database.**

My question is, is it possible to minimize these conversions (for a Java server-side) ?
(May be if I was using Node.js on server-side I could just work with JSON all thru, but I cant change from Java on the server-side).

Is what I am doing the usual way to go about it or are there optimizations possible (with respect to the data conversions) ?

Though there may be some libraries/packages that help with the conversion of Java object to JSON Document in NoSQL DB (like Morphia, Ektorp, Mongolink etc), my question is if there is a possibility of avoiding such conversions in the first place.

Comment: The process seems standard to me. I'd look into CouchDB, which stores regular JSON documents, so no server side conversions here. If you ever need to serialize/deserialize POJO you can use Jackson or GSON.

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimization that comes to mind:

For most 'reads' of the DB performed to return JSON to clients, there is no need to convert from JSON document to specialized Java object and then back to JSON to send to client.
May be the DBObject (which is a generic Java object for holding the JSON document retrieved from the NoSQL DB) is sufficient at the Java server-side, for such read operations.

The other reads are those which need to manipulate the data retrieved from the DB, and hence need to  cast it to domain specific object types. But this conversion is kind of inevitable according to me.